# I want handle the delete function by vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

This is my `Indexing.vue` component.

```
<div>
  <div v-for="data in indexingList" :key="data.indexing_id">
    <p>{{ data.indexing_name }}</p>
    <p>{{ data.indexing_url }}</p>
  </div>
  <base-button type="primary" size="sm" @click="deleteIndexing(data.indexing_id)">Delete
  </base-button>
</div>
```

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      indexingList: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getIndexingList: function() {
      this.api.getDataModule("indexing/" + store.state.journalId, "journals/v1/")
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.indexingList = res.data.indexingList;
          },
          (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
    },

    deleteIndexing: function(dVal) {
      let sVal = {};
      sVal.indexing_id = dVal;
      this.api.putData("indexing/" + store.state.journalId + "/deleteindexing", sVal)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
          },
          (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        );
    },
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.getIndexingList();
  },
}
```

I'm getting data from the server using `getIndexingList` function in the form of the API get method. And removing the data once the user clicks the delete button by using the `deleteIndexing` function in the form of the put API method.
We wrote APIs in a separate file. Here in `indexing.vue` we are just passing the APIs.

Now I want to fix the `delete(remove) function`. The data was removed from the database once the user clicks the delete button but it is not removed from the webpage. Every time I need to refresh the page to see the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Vue.delete](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete) **(this.$delete)** which also ensure that the deletion triggers the view updates.

Try this-

```
deleteIndexing: function(dVal) {
  let sVal = {};
  sVal.indexing_id = dVal;
  this.api
    .putData("indexing/" + store.state.journalId + "/deleteindexing", sVal)
    .then(
      (res) => {
        // find the item from indexingList and remove it
        // Also make sure your response has the id of the deleted item
        let index = this.indexingList.findIndex(item => item.id == res.id);
        if (index != -1) {
          this.$delete(this.indexingList, index);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
    );
},
```